# zoo-project missing lib libzoo_service.so.1.5

Tags: installation, ubuntu, wps, zoo-project

While running this command in zoo-project on ubuntu 14.04 , 64 bit

```
./zoo_loader.cgi "request=Getcapabilities&servise=wps"
```

./zoo_loader.cgi: error while loading shared libraries: libzoo_service.so.1.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

A file seems missing. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please include in your question the packages or ppa you installed zoo-project from.

Comment: What if you ask for 'request=GetCapabilities&service=WPS&'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please try to manually run the "sudo ldconfig" command. This should solve the issue in case the libzoo_service.so.1.5 is located in a directory that is referenced from /etc/ld.so.conf or /etc/ld.so.conf.d/* files.

Comment: ok. will check and get back to you shortly. Thanks .